# how to add and remove collapsible div with new id for each

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I want to use jQuery-mobile to add/remove the `div` with `data-role="collapsible"` each time user presses add or remove. And then give the new div a new id.

The clone method that I use doesn't work.

This is my 'bad' code:

```
<body>

<div data-role="page"  id="page1"> 
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>page1</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" id="collapsible">
<h3>New person</h3>
<ul >
<li>Name<input type="text"></li>
<li>Phone<input type="text"></li>
<li> <label for="date">Date Input:</label>
<li><input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="text"/></li>

                <li>  <a id="changePageButton2" data-role="button">show Calendar</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="placeholder"></div>

</div>



<button id="add">add</button>

    </div>


</body>
</html>

<script>


$('#add').click(function() {    
    var myClone = $('#collapsible').clone();

    myClone.prependTo("#placeholder");   
    return false;
    });  




    $(function() {
    $("#changePageButton2").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
    });        
});

  $(function() {
    $("#changePageButton1").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
    });        
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the clone just not rendering or not adding itself at all?

Comment: its adding 'ok' but with out the collapsible ability. :/

Answer (score 0):

Not positive I get what you want to do, but here's some fixes, see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Tbmsa/ It seems to work when I click `add`, I see a new collapsible list, just under the first.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div data-role="page"  id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>page1</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" id="collapsible">
                <h3>New person</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Name<input type="text"></li>
                    <li>Phone<input type="text"></li>
                    <li><label for="date">Date Input:</label></li>
                    <li><input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="text"/></li>
                    <li><a id="changePageButton2" data-role="button">show Calendar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="placeholder"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="add">add</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $("#changePageButton2").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
    });
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var myClone = $('#collapsible').clone();
        myClone.prependTo("#placeholder");
        return false;
    });
    $("#changePageButton1").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro. but my old problem stillremains: 
1. the new clone can'ot collapsible or open.
2. the new clone dont have new id.

tnx for your effort. :)

Comment: 2. Add a line like: `$(myClone).attr("id", "newId")` before you prepend it to `#placeholder`.

Comment: 1. The issue with cloning is that it clones the entire structure. If you  use the `[withDataAndEvents]`, so like `$("#collapsible").clone(true);` you clone the functions that operate the source. So you will need to make a new `<div>`, and add in the other parts. Trying to create an example.

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Tbmsa/7/ It needs some more work. You can clone the original `DIV` yet, it clones all of it, including all the JQM additions, so when you run `newClone.collapsible();` to init the functions on that element, the additional classes and spans cause it to render it inside in a way. An exmaple of that happening seen in an older update: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Tbmsa/4/

Comment: pahse #2 :), why cant i refer to the cloned divs it seems that i cant reach them with my functions.

example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zipo_soft/v6U86/

and i try to add a counter for the id for each clone and it doesnt work, any idea why?

tnx :)

Comment: I see the problem, your not selecting the new text fields. `$("#name").keydown();` is too obscure for what you want to do. One thing you could do is add a class to all the form elements when the collapse is clicked. For example if `$("div [data-type='collapsible']").click( function(){ $("input").addClass("displayed"); });` That way when that div is expanded, you can more easily select them by their class.

Comment: Also found a comma in one line, it should read: `newClone.attr("id", "collapsible" + count);`, and not `newClone.attr("id", "collapsible", + count);`

Comment: You also need to use `$(selector).live([event], function(){});` on objects that don't exist yet. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/v6U86/7/ Don't forget to upvote or check off the answer.

Comment: Still looking at this, at least you can see where it's going: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/v6U86/9/